# Adding to {{ html_attributes }} when a Twig Template is Used

Tags: 8, theming, hooks

I have a [Paragraph](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) Twig template that outputs FAQs in HTML format and also includes the [Google FAQ data structure](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/faqpage) in the markup. What I need to do next is include `itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/FAQPage"` into the `html` tag on any page in which that template is used, but I'm not entirely sure if:

- This is something that can be done in the faq.twig.html template, or
- If it needs to be done in the mytheme.theme file. If that's the case, I'd appreciate some guidance on how to do that when that particular Paragraph bundle is used.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: My advice is to avoid the microdata syntax at all, it is hard as hell to get all the proper markup into all the different twig template files and not destroy your website's design while doing it. Better use the JSON+LD syntax, which is one encapsuled `<script>` tag which can be placed anywhere on your page (so only edit one node.twig or paragraph.twig and you're done)

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 8 collects metadata from any template rendered on a page and puts the result in placeholders of the html template. Unfortunately the html tag in html.html.twig is not placeholdered out-of-the-box:

*html.html.twig*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html{{ html_attributes }}>
  <head>
    <head-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token }}">
    <title>{{ head_title|safe_join(' | ') }}</title>
    <css-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token }}">
    <js-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token }}">
  </head>
```

So you could add your own placeholder as dummy attribute:

*mytheme.theme*

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for html.html.twig.
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $variables['html_attributes']['html-attribute-placeholder'] = '-';
}
```

and replace it with metadata you add to the faq template:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for faq.html.twig.
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_faq(&$variables) {
  $variables['#attached'] = [
    'placeholders' => [
      'html-attribute-placeholder="-"' => [
        '#markup' => 'itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/FAQPage"',
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

You are mentioning a faq template, but if this is a paragraph you probably don't have a specific template. Then add the metadata in a paragraph preprocess hook checking the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do it in my website, so I can share a working example :

```
function mymodule_preprocess(array &$variables, string $hook) {
      if ($hook === 'paragraph' && $variables['paragraph']->getType() === 'your_paragraph_type') {
        if (is_array($variables['html_attributes'])) {
          $variables['html_attributes'] = new Attribute($variables['html_attributes']);
        }
    
        $variables['html_attributes']->setAttribute('itemscope', true);
        $variables['html_attributes']->setAttribute('itemtype', 'https://schema.org/FAQPage');
      }
}
```